# Check on grouped rows in excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel, grouping

Like the title says, I don't know how to check on a row which is grouped. I Googled it, but couldn't find anything.

this code here doesn't work:

```
if (((Excel.Range)sourceRange.Rows[i]).Group() == true)   // doesn't work
{
     ...
}
```

Does somebody know how to check a row if it is grouped or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the property `OutlineLevel` of the `Range` object. If the value is 1 it is not grouped. Greater values mean that the region is in a (eventually nested) group.

Comment: thanks ;-) in my code outlinelevel need to be 2 but this was easy to find out.

Comment: how did it return the value?   I Get 'r.OutlineLevel' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dynamic {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}