# Identify and load the Row Grouping in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a huge Excel file with around 50k rows. I am reading it using the following connection string

```
string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1'", MyFilePath);
```

In this huge Excel file, the rows are grouped in nesting pattern. Meaning, lets say first 500 rows are grouped under `Group A` there is a sub group in that group comprising of rows from 300-400 as `Group B` and then again from 350-400 
in `Group C`. Now when I read the excel file in my program, I get all the rows, but I cannot distinguish between the row grouping I mentioned above. Is there any smart way to identify and group them accordingly?

Here's a sample of my code.

```
rivate List<List<string>> ReadSheetData(string _query, bool _HasHeaders = true)
    {
        string conn = "";
        if (!_HasHeaders)
            conn = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1'", MyFilePath);
        else
            conn = this.conn;

        List<List<string>> ret = new List<List<string>>();
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(_query, connection);
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable tbl = dr.GetSchemaTable();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        List<string> rowVals = new List<string>();
                        ret.Add(rowVals);
                        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dynamic cell = dr[i];
                            string value = cell != null ? cell.ToString() : "";
                            rowVals.Add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }

        ret.RemoveAll(a => a.All(b => b == "") == true);
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `Spire.XLS` and here is the download link [DOWNLOAD](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-now.html)
Steps to use:
Load file which I want to create group.Initialize worksheet,set the grid lines as invisible. Create Groups. There are two methods, GroupByRows, GroupByColumns. For each method, we need to pass three parameters: first row/column, last row/column and a bool value which defines if the group will be folded.
Save and Launch file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944779/check-on-grouped-rows-in-excel-with-c-sharp

Comment: Is `Spire.xls`a new Excel access technique like the ACE engine in my example? If so, I need to re write whole of my methods that handle excel manipulation in my program to use `Spire.xls`. I am looking for some quick way to read and group excel. I am expecting around a min as a through put for parsing the 50K rows excel file I mentioned. Can you please elaborate on Spire.xls with an example if possible for me..?

Comment: @Sanjeev: I am reading the data of the Excel file as `List<List<string>>`. So I doubt if I can access the Range Object with this. Moreover, I am afraid if e need to use `interop.excel` if I have to get access to Range Object which is 10 times slower than what I have now. like I said, I am more interested in the scalability of the application. Any ideas there..?

Comment: Are `Group A` etc. Named ranges? AFAIK connection string approaches can query only sheets and named ranges. For more than that you can use [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854) or [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or something else to read the XML

Comment: @Slai I dont think they are Named Ranges as I can't see any names defined for them when I select the Grouped Rows. However I see some formula like `=INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37),17)` in Name Manager. This don't look like the name of a range to me. Just pasting here to confirm with you.  So, I am positive that the groups are not named ranges in my excel sheet. This is a sheet that I receive from a user. so I cannot control the format. There fore I have limited data available about its format